# Request arrives empty in laravel when sending a lot of data

Tags: php, jquery, json, laravel

I have the following doubt, I am sending an ajax request to laravel but one of the parameters has a lot of information

[image]

but in laravel using $request->all() I get an empty array, but when I send only a part of the text (approximately a quarter) the data arrives to laravel, my question is, is there a limit on post requests? If so, how could I correct this? attached ajax request code

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: _url,
        data: _data,
        success : function(response){
            console.log("sucess")
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log("ajax error" + JSON.stringify(response))
        },
    });
```

data I am sending including the token.

[image]

Comment: The limit would be imposed by your PHP and/or server configuration. Its not controllable by Laravel.

Comment: so is that it? if it exceeds a certain size, the request arrives empty? is there a config file where i can change this? Thank you

Comment: The PHP is configured in `php.ini` file. The server configuration depends on what server you are using.